# Toolbar MenuItem

Tags: android, toolbar

I have two MenuItems in my toolbar. Generally, everything works fine, but I dont know why MenuItem "feedback" also starts MenuItem "search".
Thanks in advance

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    search(searchView);
    MenuItem feedback = menu.findItem(R.id.feedback);
    feedback.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            new EasyFeedback.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .withEmail("webianks@gmail.com")
                    .withSystemInfo()
                    .build()
                    .start();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Show your menu.xml

Comment: haha  i forgot delete "app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView".... now it works perfecktly:)